# how do i make my page load after a set amount of seconds - 2 seconds using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to create an effect where the page loads after 2 seconds, by manipulating the DOM using javascript

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So you want it to display a blank screen to the user for 2 seconds? May I ask _why?_

Comment: no, I want the whole page to load after 2 seconds? so the loading time to be 2 seconds?

Comment: maybe inject all the content via JS after 2 seconds?! >< not sure why do you want to it...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='page.html'},5000);</script>
```

For index page use only '/'

```
<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="/"},3000);</script>
```

Comment: This will create an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Create absolutely positioned element and after 2 seconds fade out/disappear it.

```js
setTimeout(() => $("#layer").fadeOut(), 2000);
/*
  or if you are not using jQuery - line below
  setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('layer').style.display = 'none', 2000);
*/
```

```css
#layer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  heigth: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="layer">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

for 2 seconds delay first you have to make sure the page loaded '$(document).ready' after that you can use 'setTimeout'.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function{
/* your code goes here , what action you want to do code it here .*/
},3000/* time in milliseconds */);
});
```